# How do I resolve LoadError while trying to make a png on Windows using Julia Studio and Gadfly?

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I'm currently working through [this tutorial](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/julia-neural-networks.html) and I'm having trouble getting the png image to display. This is my program.

```
using DataFrames
using Gadfly

train_df = readtable("winequality-red.csv", separator=';')

_, count = hist(train_df["quality"])
class = sort(unique(train_df["quality"]))
value_counts = DataFrame(count=count, class=class)
#value_counts

p = plot(value_counts, x="class", y="count", Geom.bar(), Guide.title("Class distributions (\"quality\")"))
draw(PNG(14cm, 10cm), p)
```

the error I get is

```
LoadError("C:/Users/John/Desktop/helloworld.jl",12,MethodError(PNG,(140.0mm,100.0mm)))
```

I've tried some of the things mentioned in [this discussion](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/176), however I haven't made any observable progress.

Comment: I get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by installing `Cairo`.

```
Pkg.add("Cairo")
```

and changing this line

```
draw(PNG(14cm, 10cm), p)
```

to

```
draw(PNG("chart.png", 14cm, 10cm), p)
```

and then opening `chart.png` with Julia Studio

[image]

Comment: I used draw(PNG("neuroplot.png", 14cm, 10cm), NeuroPlot) for example and I got this ERROR: Cairo must be installed to use the PNG backend.  in PNG at C:\Users\ra133513\.julia\v0.3\Compose\src\Compose.jl:124